# VB.Net code for a true chart in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, charts

I wanna draw a true chart using VB.
Student John's skill:
English - 60%, 
Philosophy - 76%, 
Leadership - 52%, 
Programming - 85%, 
Other - 34%.
I wanna know the shortest code for this chart.

Comment: Can you clarify what a true chart is?

Comment: -1 and voted to close. No code, no research, just a show-me-teh-codez (or I wanna)

Comment: You want VB code but you have added C# tag, change it.

Comment: See the Chart control, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee410579.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest code ever is using [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard.html)

using the link:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chbh=a,10&chs=300x225&cht=bvg&chco=FF9900,00FF00,0000FF,3072F3,49188F&chd=t:60|72|52|85|34&chdl=English|Philosophy+|Leadership|Programming|Other&chdlp=b&chp=0.05&chma=|0,2&chtt=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F6435326

produces this chart:

[image]